# Deriving class with protected equality operator results in deleted default

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, protected

Suppose we have the following implementation:

```cpp
class A {
    protected:
    bool operator==(const A&) const = default;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    bool operator==(const B& b) const {
        return A::operator==(b);
    };
};

int main() {
    B x, y;
    x == y;
}
```

This works in `gcc 12.1` and `clang 14.0`. I also assume this to be the default behavior of `B::operator==(const B& b)` as the standard states:

> A class can define operator== as defaulted, with a return value of bool. This will generate an equality comparison of each base class and member subobject, in their declaration order. Two objects are equal if the values of their base classes and members are equal. The test will short-circuit if an inequality is found in members or base classes earlier in declaration order.

So we can just replace the above statement with `=default` right? **not really...**

```cpp
class A {
    protected:
    bool operator==(const A&) const = default;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    bool operator==(const B& b) const = default;
};

int main() {
    B x, y;
    // Fails on both clang and gcc
    // error: use of deleted function 'constexpr bool B::operator==(const B&) const'
    //     x == y;
    x == y;
}
```

If an operator's default behavior is ill-formed, then the default behavior is to implicitly delete the function. So something about the default behavior here is ill-formed.

The only hypothesis I have is we're trying to invoke `A::operator==` within the context of `A`(maybe via `std::static_cast<A>(*this) == b`), which illegal because the function is `protected` not `public`. In my implementation above we're invoking `A::operator==` from the context of `B` which is legal. I don't see where in the standardese this specific behavior is specified though.

Addendum: Here's the full compiler dump of the `=default` implementation above:

```
<source>:8:10: note: 'constexpr bool B::operator==(const B&) const' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    8 |     bool operator==(const B& b) const = default;
      |          ^~~~~~~~
<source>:8:10: error: 'bool A::operator==(const A&) const' is protected within this context
<source>:3:10: note: declared protected here
    3 |     bool operator==(const A&) const = default;
```

and I'm anticipating comments of form "why are you doing this in the first place?". The idea of removing the ability to perform `==` on the base class but allowing the derived classes to perform `==` if they so wish is a common one, but the argument for using the free function `operator==(const B& lhs, const B& rhs)` is valid. That's the current workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaulted implementation does not try to call `A::operator==(b)` for the base comparison.

It does something like `static_cast<const A&>(*this) == static_cast<const A&>(b)` instead and applies overload resolution to it as usual. This is described in [[class.eq]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.eq#2) and [[class.eq]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.eq#3). Also see [[class.compare.default]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#3) and [[class.compare.default]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#6) for relevant definitions.

The expression above will resolve to `static_cast<const A&>(*this).operator==(static_cast<const A&>(b))`. The context of the overload resolution is the class `B` however and therefore the special `protected` rule in [[class.protected]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.protected) applies, which forbids the type mismatch on the left hand of `.` and the class in which the access happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Am I correct in assuming this phrase in the standard: `by comparing corresponding elements xi and yi in the expanded lists of subobjects for x and y`, specifically "subobjects" requires the static upcast to be done?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Yes that is part of the definition of _expanded list of subobjects_ in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare.default#6.sentence-3.

Comment: thank you for that! Good to know my hypothesis was correct :)